# Google Play - 'Feature Graphic' Design

Tags: png, image-quality, compression

I recently got my application in the google play store, but I have an issue with how the 'Feature Graphic' is being displayed.

Here is the original (@ 72 DPI (Screen RES) - Saved for Web - PNG8):
[image]

Here is the Google-Play-resized version:
[image]

(The image is linked to my application, for demonstration.  Google refers to the big graphic is what they call the 'Feature Graphic').

Here are the design standards they give: http://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1078870

Why is my 'Feature Graphic' not as sharp as it should be? The original image is perfect!

Answer (score 4):

I don't work for Google so I can't speak to their method of sizing & compressing the images, but your image is very noisy which means that any modifications will significantly alter the sharpness of the textures you're using.

Noting that their guidelines warn that your graphic "will be downsized to mini or micro", and even in a desktop browser the art is reduced to a smaller size and transcoded into JPEG, you may want to think about simplifying your image if maintaining sharpness is important.

**Edit**

While editing your post, I noticed there is another link from Google with recommendations specific to Feature Graphics:  http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/10/android-market-featured-image.html

Notice that they state the following:

> Your image has to be designed to scale; it will need to look good both in a full-size Web browser and on a little handset. You can rely on the aspect ratio being constant, but not the size. Here’s a tip: Try resizing your image down to 1 inch in width. If it still looks good and conveys your brand message, you have a winner.

While you are currently focused on fixing the sharpness, you may want to rethink the entire graphic.  Just fox example, here is how your graphic would look when converted to 240px width (not uncommon on an older 'droid):

[image]

The logo is good, but the other text is practically illegible.

Comment: Ok perfect! Thank you so much, I will try using a little less grunge ;)

Comment: Expanding slightly on what Farray said, high frequency information (in this case, the noise) doesn't compress well. That's why adding a slight blur to an image can greatly reduce its jpeg file size. If Google has a kb target for this image, they'd have to apply severe compression to get there. Jpeg compression works in 8x8 pixels blocks, which mangle sharp, high-contrast edges; the higher the compression, the worse the effect. That's what kills your ultra light font, too.

Answer (score 3):

Google Play Store wants PNG24 not PNG8

**"JPEG or 24-bit PNG (no alpha)"**

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/1078870?hl=en

auto formatting from PNG8 to 24 can cause issues like that. Try saving as PNG24 :D

Comment: Very old question haha! Thanks though...